# How to breed Olympus dragons on dragonvale

Tags: dragonvale

I just got on dragonvale today and there were three new rare dragons, bronze Olympus, silver Olympus, and gold Olympus. They look strange but they are rather new so I just wanted to know if anybody was able to breed them.

Comment: Hi Nat, are you asking about Dragonvale?  I think you are, but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes it's on dragonvale, sorry bout that I will edit that

Comment: I tried scorch and bronze in the sanctuary and I got a Olympus-looking egg. It's definitly not bronze or any other type of egg I've seen so far. Maybe it's a gold egg or something else.

Answer (score 4):

While there are three types of Olympus Dragons, all three seem to be the same combination of elements: Air, Earth, Lightning and Fire. This makes -many- different dragon combinations possible as long as they posses those four elements.

When properly bred all three types appear to have the same breeding time for 35 hours.

This information was taken from the appropriate wiki pages for the [Bronze](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Bronze_Olympus_Dragon), [Silver](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Silver_Olympus_Dragon) and [Gold](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Olympus_Dragon) versions of the Olympus dragons.

Comment: Just want to add that Fire is apparently not a required element. I just bred an Earth dragon with a Sonic (Air/lightning) dragon and got an Olympus.

Comment: @Fluttershy Confirmed! Thanks for the updated info.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who just wants the most successful, specific breeding combination(s):

Sonic + Lava -OR- Blazing + Crystal

Source: Dragonvale Wikia Community

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying different combinations that I've came across and with the willow dragon and quake dragon I have an Olympus dragon already and another being bred now

WILLOW+QUAKE= Olympus

I've also heard that crystal and blazing work

There is a website called www.macenstein.com/dragonvale 
that tells you different combinations to get the dragons u want (every combination I've tried from there has worked over time)